# Is there any way to make lowercase \chi bigger?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontsize

I was just wondering if it's possible to make lower case `\chi` bigger.

Basically I want the equation `\chi^2_0 = \frac{1}{2}` to have more space between the `2` and `0` like all the textbooks have but the `\chi` I get is tiny and so the `2` and `0` basically read like `20` vertically, is there a way to fix this/make it nicer? (I'm guessing there is since every stats textbook ever seems to be able to do it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could play around with the regular text adjustments or by using `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \chi^2_0 =& \tfrac{1}{2} \\
  \mbox{\Large$\chi$}^2_0 =& \tfrac{1}{2} \\
  \scalebox{1.5}{$\chi$}^2_0 =& \tfrac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) was just used for the `align*` and `\tfrac` functionality. If cluttering your input is a problem, you can put this in a macro (here I've chosen the first enlargement style):

```
\newcommand*{\bigchi}{\mbox{\Large$\chi$}}% big chi
```

and use it as `\bigchi=\frac{1}{2}`. You can play around with different font sizes or scaling values.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted, bigger Chi. Never knew about scalebox.

Answer (score 9):

Exponents are set at the same height for all characters: there's no difference in height between `$\chi_0^2$` and `$X_0^2$`. This is *a good thing*.

Exponents are set higher when the formula is in display math mode: compare `$\chi_0^2$` and `\[\chi_0^2\]`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish what you want would be to manually specify a smaller size for the subscript and superscript. A before and after comparison:

[image]

Changing the size of the `\chi` in inline mode would probbaly have an issue with the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\centering% used to center the inline display to produce a simpler image for presentation here
Inline mode: $\chi^2_0 = \chi^{\scriptscriptstyle 2}_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}$

\[\text{Display mode: } \chi^2_0 = \chi^{\scriptscriptstyle 2}_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}\]
\end{document}
```